# Arrange the column order in insert command in LKM

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

we want to rearrange the column order in the insert command in LKM.

want to put the condition for the column list with its datatype equal blob.

```
insert <%

if ("1".equals(odiRef.getOption ("LOAD_DIRECT")))  { 

out.print("/*+ APPEND_VALUES */");

};%> into <%=odiRef.getTable("L", "COLL_NAME", "A")%>

(

<%=odiRef.getColList("", "[CX_COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "","")%>

)

values

(

<%=odiRef.getColList("", ":[CX_COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "","")%>

)
```

Comment: Please need help on this task. If somebody knows how to get only selected columns in the getCollist please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

we rearrange the columns on both source and target model and the create staging table and insert staging and target table order changed and worked.